# Implement Torquebox (2.3) into existing JBoss (7.1.x)

Tags: deployment, jboss, installation, jruby, torquebox

What is the way to implement Torquebox (2.3) into an existing JBoss environment? I've found the extensions inside the configuration file (standalone.xml):

```
<extension module="org.torquebox.bootstrap"/>
<extension module="org.torquebox.core"/>
<extension module="org.torquebox.services"/>
<extension module="org.torquebox.web"/>
<extension module="org.torquebox.messaging"/>
<extension module="org.torquebox.jobs"/>
<extension module="org.torquebox.security"/>
<extension module="org.torquebox.cdi"/>
<extension module="org.torquebox.stomp"/>
<extension module="org.projectodd.polyglot.hasingleton"/>
<extension module="org.projectodd.polyglot.cache"/>
<extension module="org.projectodd.polyglot.stomp"/>
```

... and

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:torquebox-core:1.0"/>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:torquebox-services:1.0"/>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:torquebox-web:1.0"/>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:torquebox-messaging:"/>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:torquebox-jobs:1.0"/>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:torquebox-security:1.0"/>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:torquebox-cdi:1.0"/>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:torquebox-stomp:1.0"/>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:polyglot-hasingleton:1.0"/>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:polyglot-cache:1.0"/>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:polyglot-stomp:1.0" socket-binding="stomp"/>
```

... and some port bindings like

```
<socket-binding name="stomp" port="8675"/>
```

and a directory diff (blank JBoss 7.1.1 vs Torquebox 2.3 with JBoss 7.1.1 gives me lots of diffs.

I assume there is more than just the lines above: I've seen the Hornet integration and some more modules. Does someone has done this in the past and could share experiences, an install / implementation script, some documentation or a list of modules and respected configuration settings?

Any tips, cheats, tips and tricks are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the configuration changes, there are quite a few modules within the $JBOSS_HOME/modules tree that need to be copied over as well. https://github.com/immutant/overlay is designed to overlay a TorqueBox or Immutant on to the other, or on to a vanilla AS7 install. But TorqueBox is coupled fairly closely with the version of the AS it was built against, so finding a version or incremental build that matches the base AS version may prove challenging. Your best bet is to join the #torquebox IRC channel on freenode and one of the TorqueBox devs should be able to help you out.